# Security in MVC code-first entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, security

(I also asked this question on [Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/81807/security-in-mvc-code-first-entity-framework), but not sure how many people end up seeing it there).

I am new to ASP.NET MVC and to Azure (in which our application will be hosted). And I am new to security in general. So I'm wondering how secure the use of entity framework code first in asp's scaffolding is, in and of itself.

Say you create a Model (class) with properties and then you add scaffolded Controller and Views. The scaffolding in the Views already includes the Anti Forgery Token and wraps everything in the validation. The scaffolding in the Controllers already includes to Validate the anti forgery token in HttpPost functions, and you can even specify as few properties as necessary to be bound to a view. On top of that, input through the views is setting properties of the model, and then it's the model that is being put in the Database (as opposed to specifying SQL statements to assign column values as the input from the view).

So am I understanding correctly that all this already protects you pretty well, like against things like SQL injection? If I add an encryption certificate to my application so everything is Https, then is there anything else I really need to do in the code in order to protect our code or our data? Thank you!

Comment: It is pretty good, but to keep your app secure you really do need an idea of what you are securing against. For example parameter overloading isn't protected. You might use SSL, but then you using it for everything? If not you might have a vulnerability. You might be protected against basic SQL Injection, but what about boolean SQL Injection? Its not really about what tech you are using (ASP.NET MVC) it's more knowing what you are up against

Comment: If you have access to Pluralsight, Troy Hunt does a good course on hacking. Showing how its done and tools "script kiddies" might use to automate things like SQL Injection. Also shows you how to defend and his examples are ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: @James - Pluralsight...good to know - I'll check it out.  Thanks!